# How to return whole value of arrayList in empty autocomple field

Tags: java, wicket

this is my implementation of autocompleteField:

```
        add(new AutoCompleteTextField<String>("hladaneSlovo") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String prefix) {
                return hladaneSlova.startsWith(prefix).iterator();
            }

        });
```

method startWith in my arrayList looks like:

```
public List<String> startsWith(String prefix) {
    if (prefix == null || prefix.isEmpty()) {
        return this;
    } else {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (String s : this) {
            if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

So I want to get all value when field is empty but this implementation doesnt work. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uf I found it. In `AutoCompleteTextField` is `AutoCompleteSetting` where is property `setShowListOnEmptyInput` which default value is false

so I create:

```
        AutoCompleteSettings settings = new AutoCompleteSettings();
        settings.setShowListOnEmptyInput(true);
```

and it work :)

Answer (score 1):

Code looks ok. You might want to additionally `trim()` the string before checking `isEmpty()`, maybe there are just some stray spaces around. BTW subclassing `java.util.ArrayList` is a bad idea. You should design your own class that uses a `List` internally.

Comment: Same thing, you shouldn't extend any Java collection class. There are many ways in which you can inadvertently break it that way and there is practically no reason not to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: ok never mind it doesnt works. Prefix is really empty but when there is no prexis this field is empty. There should be some other way how to display it

Comment: sorry but with option: you shouldn't extend any Java collection class I disagree ...

Comment: While everyone is certainly entitled to their opinion, yours is in disagreement with an undisputed best practice in Java. Among others, you disagree with Josh Bloch (Effective Java, 2nd, Item 16).

Comment: As far as your problem, did you make sure your method even gets called for an empty input field? I bet it doesn't.

Comment: yes it is called. Problem is when you are first on this page I want to see whole list of value and then this method isnt call so I see nothing

Comment: So it isn't called, that was my point. If it isn't called, then the code inside is irrelevant. The problem is with your framework that doesn't attempt to populate the list until the user enters something.

Comment: First of all, you definitely shouldn't extend Java collection classes. Other than that, a `TreeSet` is more appropriate for this job with its built-in `subset()` method. If you have a lot of options, a `Trie` implementation is your best bet.

Comment: @biziclop Your suggestion assumes OP has an appropriate total ordering  for his suggestions. That's not necessarily so.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik We're talking about strings here and how you can replace `startsWith()` with something that doesn't have to trawl through the entire list.

Comment: Anyway, as far as I can remember `AutoCompleteTextField` does invoke `getChoices()` on focus, whether the field is empty or not, but `startsWith()` doesn't like `null` passed to it. So you'll probably just need to add `if ( prefix == null ) prefix = "";` to the start of the method to make it work.

Comment: @biziclop We're talking about a list of suggestions here. The method `startsWith` is a member of the `LinkedList` subclass containing all the words to suggest, in the order in which to suggest them. The purpose of the method is to return all items that start with the typed-in string. I wonder why you urge OP to insert the `prefix == null` condition since it's already there.

Comment: I was talking about `s.startsWith()` but I did miss the `prefix == null` bit.